# Django Error: DatabaseError when trying to delete all rows

Tags: python, django

I am using Django 1.4.5 and following the Django 1.4 tutorial at [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/)

I have two models, which are defined as below in models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

After creating an instance of Poll in the Django shell, I tried deleting it using Poll.objects.all().delete() and received the following error:

```
DatabaseError: no such column: polls_choice.poll_id
```

Below is the entire Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 513, in delete
    collector.collect(del_query)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/deletion.py", line 175, in collect
    if not sub_objs:
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 130, in __nonzero__
    iter(self).next()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 118, in _result_iter
    self._fill_cache()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 892, in _fill_cache
    self._result_cache.append(self._iter.next())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 291, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 763, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 818, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 40, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 344, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
DatabaseError: no such column: polls_choice.poll_id
```

Thanks.

Comment: That table called `polls_choice` looks suspicious. Can you post the entire sequence of statements you entered to the Django shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a commom error produced by one of the following options:

1- You have synchronized the database before create the `Poll` model.

2- You haven't synchronized the database at all.

Try:

> python manage.py syncdb

`manage.py` is located in the root of your Django project.